# InApp purchases in iOS using ti.storekit in Appcelerator

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I'm trying to use iOS In-App Purchases in my application through ti.storekit module. I'm posting successful purchases on my custom server. Sometimes it works fine and sometimes it misses to call my custom function for posting this purchase on server. I'm confuse either this module is not compatible with titanium SDK or what.

And I'm following this tutorial by @Rodolfo Perottoni.

https://medium.com/all-titanium/monetising-your-ios-titanium-app-in-app-purchases-de35d55feb81#.yqgnj0sf2

- Titanium SDK 5.3.0
- ti.storekit version 3.1.2

I'd be thankful for your help.